# Dart/Flutter - final unmodifiable list field

Tags: flutter, list, dart, immutability, bloc

My app uses Flutter Bloc to manage app state. My state clas is defined as follows:

```
@immutable
@CopyWith()
class MyState extends Equatable {
  const ReservationsState({
    this.list1= const [],
    this.list2 = const {},
   //
   ..
   //
  final List<Reservation> list1;
  final List<Institution> list2;
}
```

So, class itself is immutable, primitive fields can't be modified. However, lists are not immutable and still it's possible to add/remove fields directly, which I don't want to be possible.

There's `List.unmodifiable()` constructor, but it's not const constructor, so this is not allowed:

```
this.list1= List.unmodifiable([]),
```

as long as `list1` is final (but it needs to be final for const constructors).

Is there any way to make truly unmodifiable final list? List needs to be created with @CopyWith extension method (generated constructor) and not allowed to be modified.

As a workaround, I can always assign `List.unmodifiable([])` in `copyWith` call, but it will only block adding elements in runtime.

Comment: Lists created with the `const` constructor are unmodifiable.

Comment: Are they? Do you metn `const []` is unmodifiable? I will check that

Comment: Yes `const []` is an unmodifiable list.

Comment: Ok, but it sill only leads to runtime error while trying to add to that list. I want collection that does not allow to add or modify, it should lead to compilation error or there should be no add/remove/modify method. However, that seems to be not possible in Dart

Comment: A [record](https://dart.dev/language/records) is immutable, and might work for some use cases. Other than that, you can create a custom immutable data structure (or try to find an existing library that does so).

Comment: Well, I still have unsound null safety, so I can't use Dart 3

Comment: One other thing you could consider is to declare the properties as `Iterable<X>` rather than `List<X>`. `List` implements from `Iterable`, and I don't believe any of those methods have mutable side effects. You can still assign `const []` to a variable of type `Iterable<X>`.

Comment: `Iterable` seems to be better, but still it could be casted to List and user may try to add items (that most likely will cause exeception) . But ok, that's more than nothing.

Comment: I mean the user could do a million other things that would cause a runtime exception as well. You can't make it totally impossible for a user to write a bad program.